# Particles not appearing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

I have made a smoke particle effect that I instantiate everytime the player shoots, its working but can not be seen with the background. If I delete the background it's visible, I've tried changing the ordering layer, creating a new layer and putting it above the default, but no matter what it's still below the background. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are developping a 2D game, you can use the z axis to set the distance of the elements to the camera (what will be the equivalent to the order of render)

Usually in a 2D game you will have the main camera at -10 in the z axis. So moving in the inspector the backgroun to, lets say z=5 or z=10, and keeping in you particle system in z=0 should solve your problem.

Try this easy trick and let me know if you are still facing problems.

You can check the second half of this [video](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/adding-a-background?playlist=17147) for a better understanding

Comment: yeah I'm confused, Y value would just shift everything upwards wouldn't it? Thanks for the help

Comment: I fixed it it was actually the Z value, other people were having the same problem, thanks so much man!

Comment: Uff the z value, I wrote it wrong. I will edit the anwser.

Comment: sorry about that, I marked it as solved. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are making a 3D game you can go to the material of the particles and make sure that render face is set to both. I just had that problem and it was annoying me. but that fixed it.